# What is @context and why is it red?

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm using the BlazoredTypeahead component in a blazor server side app and I'd like to know where the @context keyword is coming from.

The following code runs fine, but VS is reporting that it Cannot resolve symbol 'context'. Naturally, I'm curious why it works and where context is coming from.

```
@inject IEquipmentService EquipmentService
@inject AppDataService AppDataService
<h3>ModelSelect</h3>

<BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="SearchModels"
                   @bind-Value="equipModel">
    <SelectedTemplate>
        @context.model
    </SelectedTemplate>
    <ResultTemplate>
        @context.model (@context.model_desc)
    </ResultTemplate>
</BlazoredTypeahead>

@if (equipModel != null)
{
    <p>Selected model is: @equipModel.model</p>
}

@code {


    private EquipModel equipModel;


    private async Task<IEnumerable<EquipModel>> SearchModels(string searchText)
    {
        var result = await EquipmentService.SearchModels(AppDataService.CurrentContact, searchText);

        return await Task.FromResult(result.ToList());
    }


}
```

Comment: That should respond : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#template-context-parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you define a RenderFragment property in a component, you actually define a delegate that encapsulates a method that has a single parameter of type T, as for instance:

```
RenderFragment<TItem> RowTemplate
```

When you execute the delegate like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Items)
 {
     <tr>@RowTemplate(item)</tr>
 }
```

You're calling the delegate for each item in a list of items, passing the delegate an item object, say a Pet object (Note that the type specifier of delegate here is generic. **@context** is an internal variable provided by Blazor that contain the value passed to the delegate, as for instance:

```
<RowTemplate>
  <td>@context.ID</td>
  <td>@context.Name</td>
</RowTemplate>
```

Note: The content within the opening and closing of the RowTemplate element represents the fragment of content that is produced by the RowTemplate RenderFragment delegate... once again when the content is produced, you get the value passed to the delegate and use it. If the value is a Pet object, for example, with two fields, you can access the value of the fields by using expression like @context.Name.

Note that there is a way to use the type name of the object passed instead of using @context, but that's another story.

> but VS is reporting that it Cannot resolve symbol 'context'

This is a warning, right ? I did not inspect your code, but it seems to me that the type specifier used is the generic type, and VS cannot resolve the underlying type. In my example the type specifier is TItem, but the type of the list of items passed to the `RenderFragment<TItem> RowTemplate`  property is of type Pet.

As far as I recall, previously there was an issue with the generic type, and you had to pass the underlying type passed to a templated component... You had to write your code like this:

Usage of templated component:

```html
 <TableTemplate TItem="Pet" Items="pets">

 </TableTemplate>
```

As you can see we assign a list of Pet objects named `"pets"` to the Items attribute, but we had also to specify the type of the objects passed in the list (`TItem="Pet"`). As far as I know this issue was solved, perhaps the code of BlazoredTypeahead was written before?

Comment: You said : " Note that there is a way to use the type name of the object passed instead of using @context, but that's another story". do you have any resources to read about that ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Resharper?  If so, that may well be the cause - Resharper's Blazor support is very much still work in progress at present (although definitely improving).

There's a specific support case related to the `@context` issue titled ['Blazor template context parameters are marked as unresolved symbols'](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-477950).

There's 'an ugly workaround' mentioned in the comments for that post that I've included below, but I'd suggest not doing that and waiting for JetBrains to fix the underlying issue:

```cs
@code {
    private Pet context;
}
...
<td>@context.PetId</td>
...
```

For general Blazor progress in Resharper check ['Blazor support'](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-469186).